# SQL Injection in Code/Static SQL (T-SQL)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-injection, parameterized

Are parametrized static/code SQL statements subject to SQL injection attacks?

For example, let's say I have the following simplified stored procedure:
Does the fact that I am passing the input **@PSeries_desc** mean I am subject to injection attacks if it is parameterized? 
Previously, this was a dynamic SQL statement and the code was executed using `exec` as opposed to **sp_executesql** So, it definitely was open to attacks.

```
CREATE procedure get_product_by_title
   @PSearchType int = NULL
  , @Pseries_desc varchar(40) = NULL
as
begin

declare
  @whereLikeBeg varchar(1)
, @whereLikeEnd varchar(1)

set @whereLikeBeg = ''
set @whereLikeEnd = ''

if @search_code = 'contains'
begin
  set @whereLikeBeg = '%'
  set @whereLikeEnd = '%'
end

if @search_code = 'starts_with'
begin
  set @whereLikeEnd = '%'
end

select
    distinct B.parent_product_id
    , B.parent_product_id
from
    tableA

where
    parent_product_id = child_product_id
    and product_title like @whereLikeBeg + @Pseries_desc + @whereLikeEnd
end
```

Comment: You really should show the calling code (C# or VB) from the DAL to see if its safe.

Comment: Unfortunately, the existing code base is in classic ASP. Hooray for legacy applications!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code look safe to me...

Parametrized query is not the only way to protect yourself from SQL-injection attacks but it's probably the simplest and safest way to do it.

And even if you forget about the sql-injection attacks, building query dynamically is not a good practice, especially when you are working with strings because they might contains SQL reserved words / characters that will have an impact on your query.

Comment: I agree. I would use dynamic SQL only if I had to. Even if you use sp_executesql and pass in parametrized data, it's still really difficult to debug.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using parameterized queries in the access code, you don't need to worry. Checking for it inside the stored procedure is improper.